# DataGrid's Paging is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagrid, pagination

i'm trying to add paging to my datagrid but it doesnt show up, instead the datagrid only show page number 1 and i am not able to click the page number

this is my **aspx**

```
<asp:DataGrid ID="grid1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
AllowPaging="True" PageSize="5" AllowCustomPaging="true" 
OnPageIndexChanged="grid1_PageIndexChanging">

<HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Height="30px"></HeaderStyle>
     <Columns>
         <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="ID" >
            <HeaderStyle Font-Underline="false" Height="15px" Width="5%" HorizontalAlign="Center" BackColor="#ccffcc"></HeaderStyle>
                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></ItemStyle>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label id="lblID" runat="server" text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ID_")%>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateColumn>
      </Columns>
      <PagerStyle Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="black" HorizontalAlign="left" Wrap="True" Mode="NumericPages" />
      <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
      </asp:DataGrid>
```

and on my **aspx.cs** i have added `BindGrid()` but it won't work

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        BindGrid();
    }
}

protected void grid1_PageIndexChanging(object source, DataGridPageChangedEventArgs e)
{
    grid1.CurrentPageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    grid1.VirtualItemCount = 1000;
    BindGrid();
}

private void BindGrid() 
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    con.ConnectionString = gc.GetWebConfigConnectionStringAIS();
    con.Open();
    string query = "SELECT ID_ FROM dbo.Testing";
    cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

    using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        grid1.DataSource = dr;
        grid1.DataBind();
    }

    con.Close();
    grid1.Visible = true;
}
```

Comment: Remove `AllowCustomPaging="true"`

Comment: @VDWWD an error will occur if i remove it. it says `AllowCustomPaging must be true and VirtualItemCount must be set for a DataGrid with ID 'grid1' when AllowPaging is set to true and the selected data source does not implement ICollection.`

Comment: AH. I did remove the VirtualCount also when testing. But why not use a GridView? A DataGrid has been replaced by it for a very long time now.

Answer (score 0):

Verify that you have enough data that can be populated to more that one page

Comment: i did, i set the pagesize to  5 when i have 7 records on database

Answer (score 0):

## Use DataSet to resolve your issue

```
private void BindGrid() 
{
    //declare DataSet attribute
    SqlDataAdapter da;  
    DataSet ds = new DataSet(); 

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    con.ConnectionString = gc.GetWebConfigConnectionStringAIS();
    con.Open();
    string query = "SELECT ID_ FROM dbo.Testing";
    cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

    //here happens the magic
    cmd.Connection = con;  
    da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);  
    da.Fill(ds);  
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    //using dataset instead of reader will resolve your issue
    Grid.DataSource = ds;  
    Grid.DataBind();  

    using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        grid1.DataSource = dr;
        grid1.DataBind();
    }

    con.Close();
    grid1.Visible = true;
}
```

["DataGrid.AllowCustomPaging Property"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datagrid.allowcustompaging?view=netframework-4.7.2)  **Official Documentation**